# Saving a javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a table outputted by the [pivottable.js](http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/onrefresh.html) plugin.

The problem is, from my setCookie function I am successfully console.logging "cookie saved". When I refresh the page my check cookie function console.logs "no cookie".

What am I doing wrong here that is not allowing me to correctly save my cookie and then retrieve it when I come back/refresh to the page?

The cookie value is stored in the config_copy variable. Here I am calling my setCookie() function which saves the config_copy variable into the cookie:

```
function(config) {
                    var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));

                        setCookie();

                    }
```

setCookie() I want to save the var config_copy into this cookie

```
 function setCookie(key,config_copy){
    console.log("cookie saved");

};
```

When the page loads, I want to get my cookie I previously saved:

```
function getCookie(key){
    var name = key + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
};
```

checkCookie() function:

```
    function checkCookie() {
    var cookie = getCookie();
    if (cookie != "") {
        console.log("cookie exists");
    } else {
       console.log("no cookie");
    }
};
```

Comment: where are you code to save the cookie? i don't see any code to save it

Comment: my setCookie() function

Comment: but you are missing the "save cookie" statement. look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```js
function setCookie(key,config_copy){
    document.cookie = key + "=" + config_copy;
    console.log("cookie saved");
};
```